# Create a new calculated column on groupby in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe in Pyspark which is already inside a groupby by the column "accountname".

```
accountname |   namespace   |   cost    |   cost_to_pay
account001  |   ns1         |   93      |   9
account001  |   Transversal |   93      |   25
account002  |   ns2         |   50      |   27
account002  |   Transversal |   50      |   12
```

I need a new column that is the `"cost" - "cost_to_pay"` where `"namespace" == "Transversal"`, I need this result in all the fields of the new column, something like this:

```
accountname |   namespace   |   cost    |   cost_to_pay |   new_column1                                         
account001  |   ns1         |   93      |   9           |   68                    
account001  |   Transversal |   93      |   25          |   68
account002  |   ns2         |   50      |   27          |   38
account002  |   Transversal |   50      |   12          |   38
```

68 is the result of subtracting 93 - 25 for the groupby from account001.
And 38 the result of subtracting 50 - 12 for account002.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the difference for each accountname using the maximum of a masked difference:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'new_column1',
    F.max(
        F.when(
            F.col('namespace') == 'Transversal',
            F.col('cost') - F.col('cost_to_pay')
        )
    ).over(Window.partitionBy('accountname'))
)

df2.show()
+-----------+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
|accountname|  namespace|cost|cost_to_pay|new_column1|
+-----------+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
| account001|        ns1|  93|          9|         68|
| account001|Transversal|  93|         25|         68|
| account002|        ns2|  50|         27|         38|
| account002|Transversal|  50|         12|         38|
+-----------+-----------+----+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

if `df` is your dataframe after `groupby`, you can find a `df_temp` using:

```
df_temp = df.filter(F.col('namespace')=='Transversal')
df_temp = df_temp.withcolumn('new_column1', F.col('cost') - F.col('cost_to_pay'))
df_temp = df_temp.select('accountname', 'new_column1') ## keep only relevant columns
## you might want to have some extra checks, like droping duplicates, etc

## and finally join df_temp with you main dataframe df
df = df.join(df_temp, on='accountname', how='left')
df = df.na.fill({'accountname':'some predefined value, like 0}) ## if you wish to fill nulls
```